# spring boot security with Microsoft azure AD

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, azure-active-directory

Currently working with node.js for UI and spring boot for backend webservice. we have registered the UI with Microsoft azure and sending the required properties from config.js.
Similiarly I want the backend webservice to be secured using the same SSO registartion.

I have mentioned the below properties in application.properties

```
azure.activedirectory.clientId="xyz"
azure.activedirectory.clientSecret="123"
azure.activedirectory.ActiveDirectoryGroups="groupname"
security.oauth2.client.clientAuthenticationScheme=form 
security.oauth2.client.scope=profile
```

and the MySecurityConfig.java

```
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true,
    prePostEnabled = true)

public class MySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AADAuthenticationFilter aadAuthFilter;
@Autowired
OAuth2ClientContextFilter oAuth2ClientContextFilter;
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     /* http.authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()//any other request just need 
         authentication
          .and()
          .formLogin();//enable form login*/
         http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
      http.addFilterAfter(aadAuthFilter, 
      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

  }
}
```

when followed the same steps mentioned in the azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter examples, I'm getting the below Exception:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException: A redirect is required to get the users approval
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.getRedirectForAuthorization(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:359) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:205) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
```